# How to use selenium in Python to extract texts in "VIEW MORE"?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, innerhtml

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'XXXX\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://websummit.com/speakers')
```

https://websummit.com/speakers

Hi folks,
I am using Selenium in Python to extract the speakers' information from the above website, but having trouble to extract further info under the "VIEW MORE".

I can only extract the 25 speakers information each time by clicking the "VIEW MORE", but I hope to find a better solution which doesn't need to click the "VIEW MORE" and extract them all.

[image]

Below is my code:

```
speakers=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.speaker__content__inner')))
speakers_list = []
for e in speakers:
    speakers_list.append(e.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
print(speakers_list)
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you look at the HTML of the page, the other speakers aren't there until you click VIEW MORE. Why are you using `innerHTML`? If you used `.text` you wouldn't have to parse the info and clean out the HTML tags.

Comment: you have to `click()` this button with `"VIEW MORE"`

Comment: So you want to get the data without loading it first? *scratches head*

Comment: I want to get the data in the "VIEW MORE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I hope to find a better solution which doesn't need to click the "VIEW MORE" and extract them all.

addition to this you really don't need to use selenium if your intention is to get only this information, you can simply look at `requests` library -  below is the code which will give you all information on the page.

```
import requests
import json
for i in range(15):
    req = requests.get('https://api.cilabs.com/conferences/ws19/lists/speakers?per_page=25&page='+str(i))
    if(req.status_code == 200):
        josn2 = req.json()
        data = josn2.get('data')
        records = []
        for x in data:
            records.append({"name" : x.get('first_name') + " "+ str(x.get('last_name')),
              "job_title" : x.get('job_title'),
              "company_name" : x.get('company_name'),
              "country" : x.get('country')})
    print(records)
print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! request library solved my problem so well!

Comment: Do you mind telling me how did you find the link "https://api.cilabs.com/conferences/ws19/lists/speakers?"

Comment: sure, go to developer tool or press f12 on keyboard you will see network move to it, now click on VIEW MORE you will see the api call with response in network tab and there you go with it

Comment: Got it! Really appreciate your help!